# how to find the code that prevent wordpress text selection?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I know this may be stupid and simple question but I really need help
there,s a wordpress website that have been created by someone and there is a text copy protection that I have no Idea how he applied to the website . I checked wordpress plugins and even tried additional css code but none of them disable that text copy protection . How can I find the code or the thing that prevent text copy protection ?
thank u so much
website address : https://www.lanamind.com/

Comment: is here - https://i.ibb.co/Vp9w2Mj/image.png

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/dW1LmLd/image.png

Comment: I seem to be able to copy the text. Is there one specific part that can’t be copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added two options and both are working for me.

1. If you want to achieve this using plugin [All in one security](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/) plugin provides this option where you can add copy protection. A plugin will always be the better option for this feature and this plugin has many other settings to secure your site.

Take a look here:

[image]

2. If you don't want to use this plugin you can add this code in your PHP file. I have tested it and it is working.

```php
    function output_copy_protection_code() {
        ?>
        <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no"><!-- disable image toolbar (if any) -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /*<![CDATA[*/
            document.oncontextmenu = function() {
                return false;
            };
            document.onselectstart = function() {
                console.log("here");
                if (event.srcElement.type != "text" && event.srcElement.type != "textarea" && event.srcElement.type != "password") {
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            if (window.sidebar) {
                document.onmousedown = function(e) {
                    var obj = e.target;
                    if (obj.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'SELECT'
                            || obj.tagName.toUpperCase() == "INPUT"
                            || obj.tagName.toUpperCase() == "TEXTAREA"
                            || obj.tagName.toUpperCase() == "PASSWORD") {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                };
            }
            document.ondragstart = function() {
                return false;
            };
            /*]]>*/
        </script>
        <?php
    }

add_action('init', 'output_copy_protection_code');
```

Comment: thank you for your response . you mean I add this code to the functions.php file? cause I tried and didn't work

Comment: Yes, you need to add this code in functions.php. it should work because I tested in multiple projects. You can always use the plugin I have mentioned meanwhile I will test the code again.

Comment: @matinsaber Yep, I tested again and the code is working.